# How to run multiple sqlplus queries in bash loop with only 1 connection

Tags: sql, linux, bash, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to pass multiple Oracle queries via sqlplus using a bash script that involves a loop. My script works fine, however, because it is inside a loop it opens and closes a database connection every loop. I need to open just 1 connection in the beginning of the script, then run all the queries I need then close the database connection at the end of the script.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

    anArrayToLoopThrough=($(sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
    connect schemaname/password@database
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
    set echo off feedback off verify off heading off sqlprompt '';
    select someColumn from someTable where someColumn = someValue;
    exit;
    EOF
    ))

for x in "${anArrayToLoopThrough[@]}";
    do
        someDataINeed=($(sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
        connect schemaname/password@database
        whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
        set echo off feedback off verify off heading off sqlprompt '';
        select $x from someTable where someCondition = someValue;
        exit;
        EOF
        ))
    done
```

I need to re-work this code to not spam opening/closing new DB connections in the thousands.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You could build a sqlplus script using your first query and then execute it instead of your loop. Would that work?

Comment: Hi Bobby thank you for your suggestion. I don't know if that will work for me in my case but I will try it out. My script is complex with more than a few nested loops. I think I am looking for another syntax to open the initial connection do some bash functions, run a few queries, do some bash functions, run a few queries and so on without the open-query-close syntax I am using for my sqlplus connection.

Comment: Each time you call `sqlplus`, it is a new process and a new Oracle connection.  Bash doesn't have the right constructs to reuse a database connection.  You have to try other languages like Perl or Python to achieve your goal.  As a workaround in Bash, you can generate the SQLPlus script in a loop and invoke `sqlplus` with it, in one shot.

Comment: You could ditch bash and write it in Python. :) Actually, maybe you could do it in PL/SQL and call a PL/SQL proc or block from bash if you need that.

Comment: I'm not at a command prompt right now but in ksh you could use a [coprocess](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/coprocesses.html). I'm not sure whether bash has this feature though.

Answer (score 0):

Build the selects into a variable and execute them out of the for loop

`for x in "${anArrayToLoopThrough[@]}";
    do
        queries="${queries}"$(echo -e "select $x from someTable where someCondition = someValue;\n")
    done
someDataINeed=($(sqlplus -s /nolog <<-EOF
    "connect schemaname/password@database
    whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
    set echo off feedback off verify off heading off sqlprompt '';
    ${queries}
    exit;
EOF
))`